# put a placeholder image until relevant image is loaded

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, image

I am working on a rails app. The search page shows all listings with images fetched from amazon s3. The issue am facing now is that my layout getting messy until all the image is loaded fully. So i put a placeholder image and now the issue is that how to replace it when the actual image is loaded from s3..How can we know the image is fully loaded and change the image accordingly?  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [lazysizes](https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes) or for the buzzword 'lazy loading'. It does exactly what you need I believe.

UPDATE

Check the [demo](http://afarkas.github.io/lazysizes/#examples), for example the section titled 'Image with LQIP technique'.

so basically your image tag should be now

```
<img src="placeholder-image.jpg" data-src="aws-image.jpg" class="lazyload" />
```

This image tag will display the placeholder image now. The library's javascript file will auto load the aws image once this image is scrolled into view and the aws file is loaded.

Comment: still cant figure out how this can help with my scenario..I need to replace the placeholder image when actual image loads..

Comment: havent tried it..I found another way..So now instead of showing a placeholder I set a height and width for keeping the layout from breaking while its loading..then i put a loader background .gif image..That way I dont have to remove the placeholder ot loader as it will be in background..Dont know how much efficient but now working like charm..